# Why does one script work but not the other in require.js?

Tags: requirejs, magento2.2.6, requirejs-config.js

I am trying to add a live chat script to my Magento 2 site. I had previously added slick.js to my Magento 2 site and the require-config.js file looked like this-

```
var config = {
paths: {
    slick: 'js/slick.min',
},
shim: {
    slick: {
        deps: ['jquery']
    }
}
};
```

Everything worked. I took the script from the live chat company and placed it in customscript.js in the same folder that slick is in. I changed my require-cinfig.js to-

```
var config = {
paths: {
    slick: 'js/slick.min',
    slaask: 'js/customscript'
},
shim: {
    slick: {
        deps: ['jquery']
    }
}
};
```

I have cleared all the static content and the cache. But the live chat box does not display. When I look into my require-config.js linked to from the header it shows-

```
require.config(config);
})();
(function() {
var config = {
paths: {
    slick: 'js/slick.min',
    slaask: 'js/customscript'
},
shim: {
    slick: {
        deps: ['jquery']
    }
}
};
```

I have contacted the chat company and the blame Magento. I have contacted Magento and they blame the chat company. How can I get this working?

Edit:
Copy of the script

```
!function(){var x=document.createElement("script");x.src="https://cdn.slaask.com/chat.js",x.type="text/javascript",x.async="true",x.onload=x.onreadystatechange=function(){var x=this.readyState;if(!x||"complete"==x||"loaded"==x)try{

_slaask.init('4942661a635c280f5');

}catch(x){}};var t=document.getElementsByTagName("script")[0];t.parentNode.insertBefore(x,t)}();
```

Comment: Where in the template files are you calling the chat script? In the `require-config.js` you are registering the script but that alone doesn't call the script onto the page.

Comment: @circlesix I am not calling it in any template files. Should I try and call it in the header?

Comment: to start, you could do that, just to get it on the page. in the `app/design/frontend/{vendor}/{theme}/Magento_Theme/templates/html/header.phtml` do something like: `<script type="text/x-magento-init">{"*": {"slaask": {}}}</script>`. from there you should be able to open the network tab in your developer tools on the browser and see that your `slaask.js` file is loaded.

Comment: @circlesix The good news is it shows but it throws a bunch of errors in the console- https://imgur.com/47ZT3J1 It will break all my other js. This exact script works fine on Magento 1.

Comment: that's hard to say. If there are other scripts that aren't being loaded in correctly, this will happen. require js is very picky, and i think you will find that sometimes the page will error and other times it wont. This is because require is loading scripts at different times on different pages. without the code base, there is no way to pin point why this is happening, but odds are good that there are other scripts being loaded on the page without require js, and that is the underlying issue.

Comment: The only other script I have setup slick.js for the slider. I just looked to doublecheck and there is nothing else on the page that is not part of the Magento core.

Comment: could you post the content of your script file in with your question? if there is an error, and you are sure it's not the core, then your script itself might be causing issues. Also, make sure that your content in the `pub/static/frontend` is showing up right. sometimes the deploy isn't right and the browser is seeing an old version of the file.

Comment: @circlesix Added the script in the original post.

Comment: try this: `define([],
    function() {
        var x=document.createElement("script");x.src="https://cdn.slaask.com/chat.js",x.type="text/javascript",x.async="true",x.onload=x.onreadystatechange=function(){var x=this.readyState;if(!x||"complete"==x||"loaded"==x)try {
            _slaask.init('4942661a635c280f5');
        } catch(x){}};
            var t=document.getElementsByTagName("script")[0];
            t.parentNode.insertBefore(x,t);
    }
);`

Comment: @circlesix I currently have exactly what you posted in a file called customscript. I called the script like in your second comment yesterday. My current require-config.js looks like the second one posted in the original post. The error I get is- Uncaught Error: Mismatched anonymous define() module: function(){return c()}
http://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#mismatch
    at makeError (require.js:166)
    at intakeDefines (require.js:1221)
    at require.js:1408

Comment: oh, try switching `define` for `require`. i always get that one wrong, so i just try both and see what happens. I never learned the rules on which one you use in which cases.

Comment: @circlesix switched define for require and now I get three errors.Uncaught TypeError: Constr is not a constructor twice and Uncaught Error: Mismatched anonymous define() module: . It shows up, it just seems like it breaks everything when it does. If the script didn't work just fine in Magento 1 I would wonder if it was that.

Comment: magento 1 and 2 are completely different systems. so there is nothing to say that one will work with the other. sorry i'm not able to track this down with you.

Comment: @circlesix I appreciate the help. If I get it I will post back.

Comment: @circlesix I answered the question. It is now working. This was a strange one.

Comment: nice!!! good to hear we are both not going crazy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I received this back from the developer of the plugin- Haha yes, actually we were using plugins that were using an incompatible way to use the define function, and the error was triggered at the next define call (from other modules), which explains why it was breaking modules already present on your website.

That has been fixed and now everything works fine. I was able to just paste it in the header.